# Adobe Animate CC produces - Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes error in Chrome

Tags: json, createjs, gsap, banner-ads, animate-cc

I have been following along with this tutorial [Greensock Quick start](http://greensock.com/animatecc-quickstart) and downloaded the sample files. Everything works great, but when I added images to the banner and publish from Adobe Animate CC the banner ad works great, but if I were then to open up the same .html file locally I get this error.

> Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http,
>   data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.

Is this due to the fact that I'm trying to look at a local file? It seems to work fine in FireFox. I know I can use a program like Codekit or MAMP to view this file, but I'm worried if I were to send the file to the client and they try to open it, they will not see the banner ad. What can I do to get these files working locally in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does this for security reasons, I'm having this issue with Animate CC files.
A thread I found that explains it and some solutions.
[Link to stackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome)